# How to externalize the properties of a jacoco javaagent

Tags: java, jacoco

I'm trying to get code coverage data from a remote server, so I added a JVM argument:

**-javaagent:/opt/jacocoagent.jar=output=tcpserver,port=6300,includes="a pretty long list"**

but unfortunately the includes list is too long, that the java command has exceeded the maximum length of our system limits.

Is there any way to specify a external property file so I can put the long "includes list” there?

I've read the jacoco document, it seems when running in "Offline Instrumentation", the jacoco agent will read properties from jacoco-agent.properties if it appears in classpath. But I don't want to use this mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution myself.
When oracle JVM startup, it picks an environment variable **JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS** and

> the JNI_CreateJavaVM function (in the JNI Invocation API) prepends the
>   value of the environment variable to the options supplied in its
>   JavaVMInitArgs argument.

So in my case, I defined: 
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-javaagent:/path/to/jacocoagent.jar=output=tcpserver,address=*,port=6300,includes="**a pretty long list**"

For details, you can refer to:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/envvars002.html

Comment: You right - JaCoCo does not provide way to pass properties via file, when you use agent and not "offline mode". But as stated in http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/agent.html : "Except for performance optimization or technical corner cases this option is normally not required." Note that this option does not affect generation of report, which has separate exclusions. So wondering - what are the reasons for such big list? why it can't be reduced by usage of package patterns? or maybe inverted list - exclusions, will be shorter?

Comment: Hi Godin - Some of classes in our project dependency are not be able to be instrumented, they will cause server startup error

Comment: And what is the reason of inability to instrument? And still wondering why list is long - if this is about dependency and not your code, you should be able to simply include/exclude all at once (using pattern with * wildcard), given that your code and dependency use different packages.